# rails path helper not recognized in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I have a teams model. My route.rb file for teams looks like this:

```
resources :teams
```

In my teams_controller.rb file the line `team_path(Team.first.id)` works however the `team_path` url helper is not recognized in my model team.rb. I get this error message:

```
 undefined local variable or method `team_path' for # <Class:0x00000101705e98>
 from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

I need to find a way for the model to recognize the `team_path` path helper.

Comment: I think you have to avoid using helpers in your models. Helpers are useful in views and controllers. Anyway, what is the error message and how exactly are you going to use the helper?

Comment: They usually are helpful in just views and controllers but for this particular case I need the path helper in my model. I get this error `undefined local variable or method `team_path' for #<Class:0x00000101705e98>
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to call the url_helpers this way:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.team_path(Team.first.id)
```

Comment: It is certainly not "The Rails Way."

Comment: Its absolutely fine for models to be responsible for knowing their own location, i.e. URL. Doubly true for CMS-related models like `Page`, `Article`, etc, but its fine for any model with a URL to know it.

Comment: Thanks for that Eliot. I will defer to your good judgment and edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

Consider solving this [as suggested in the Rails API docs for `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0541a0d5481043a9c78371446389794944daf3f0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L70-L83):

```
# This generates, among other things, the method <tt>users_path</tt>. By default,
# this method is accessible from your controllers, views and mailers. If you need
# to access this auto-generated method from other places (such as a model), then
# you can do that by including Rails.application.routes.url_helpers in your class:
#
#   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#     include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
#
#     def base_uri
#       user_path(self)
#     end
#   end
#
#   User.find(1).base_uri # => "/users/1"
```

In the case of the `Team` model from the question, try this:

```
# app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def base_uri
    team_path(self)
  end
end
```

---

Here is an alternative technique which I prefer as it adds fewer methods to the model.

Avoid the `include` and use `url_helpers` from the `routes` object instead:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  delegate :url_helpers, to: 'Rails.application.routes'

  def base_uri
    url_helpers.team_path(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Models are not supposed to be dealing with things like paths, redirects or any of that stuff.  Those things are purely constructions of the view or the controller.

The model really should be just that; a model of the thing that you are creating.  It should fully describe this thing, allow you to find instances of it, make changes to it, perform validations upon it... But that model wouldn't have any notion of what path should be used for anything, even itself.

A common saying in the Rails world is that if you're finding it difficult to do something (like call a path helper from a model) you are doing it wrongly.  Take this to mean that even if something is possible, if it is hard to do in Rails it is likely not the best way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to store multiple paths of different teams in a json string along with other attributes of a team and have them rendered to a tooltip when a certain html element is being hovered on. So this isn't a typical redirect situation. I made a method in my model that creates this json string with all my attributes. The link is something I just thought of and Im not sure how I would implement this logic in the controller without putting a lot of heavy logic in the controller as well. It makes the most sense to just get it in the model to me.

Answer (score 0):

to add on the previous answer you can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` just add in route `:as` like the following example:

```
get "sessions/destroy/:param_id", as: :logout
```

so you can use it as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.logout_path(:param_id => your_value)
```

Hopefully, this would help